# Css block and inline element in one

Tags: html, css

I want a semantic way to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/beydg/

The design requires each line of text to have its own white background stripe, this screams for an inline element.

At the same time I need to maintain the ability to have spacing between paragraphs, something a inline element can't achieve.

Right now the only way to achieve this was to wrap the text-nodes inside the p element with additional span elements, which is a very un-nice and un-semantic way to do it.

I'm open to all kinds of solutions that get rid of the spans. Feel free to use modern css, pseudo selectors, etc.

Bonus points if you find a way to add left/right padding to each line (right now I can only add padding at the end and beginning of each span, not at the end/beginning of each line though).

Comment: Ok, so I've experimented around some more and I came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/beydg/3/ It does what I want without the spans. Now I'd just need some padding at the beginning and end of each line, but I'm not sure if this is possible at all...

Comment: The one in your comment looks good... if it solves your problem, write it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I'll wait a bit longer to see if anybody comes up with a better solution, if not I'll use my own solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution (simplified) so far I could come up with:

```
p {
    display: inline;
}

p:after  {
    content: '\a\a';
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Works simply by setting the paragraphs to display inline and inserting two new lines with white-space set to pre via the after pseudo element.

Check it out in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/beydg/3/

It sill didn't solve the issue with padding at the beginning and end of each line, but this wasn't a priority.

Answer (score 0):

@ximi, your updated solution without the `span`'s is cool!

for the padding, you could just put the paragraphs in a container and give that a padding-left or padding-right. Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3JxY/

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but I was looking for padding inside the white container.

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of it.

### HTML

```
<div class='striped-text'>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed odio dui.</p>

<p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>

<p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    background: url(http://flickholdr.com/800/800) no-repeat;
}
div.striped-text p {
    padding: 5px;
}
div.striped-text p:nth-of-type(2n) {
    color: #000;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #999;
    /*
    ** Can give a different padding here for even elements
    ** Other properties can be added too
    */
}
div.striped-text p:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #999;
    /*
    ** Can give a different padding here for odd elements
    ** Other properties can be added too
    */
}
```

Check out the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/mSXqF/)

---

### UPDATE

Here is the link to the updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/mSXqF/3/)

### HTML

```
<div class='striped-text'>
    <div class='text-container'>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
    </div>

    <div class='text-container'>
        <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
    </div>

    <div class='text-container'>
        <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    background: url(http://flickholdr.com/800/800) no-repeat;
}
div.striped-text div.text-container {
    padding: 0 1em;
}
div.striped-text div.text-container:nth-of-type(2n) {
    padding: 0 1em;
    /*
    ** Can give a different padding here for even elements
    */
}
div.striped-text div.text-container:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    padding: 0 1em;
    /*
    ** Can give a different padding here for even elements
    */
}
div.striped-text div.text-container p {
    padding: 5px;
}
div.striped-text div.text-container:nth-of-type(2n) > p {
    color: #000;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #999;
    /*
    ** Insert other properties here
    */
}
div.striped-text div.text-container:nth-of-type(2n+1) > p {
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #999;
    /*
    ** Insert other properties here
    */
}
```

Comment: Pretty, but not what was asked for.

Comment: @ChrisMarasti-Georg I guess this was what he asked for. With the use of pseudo-selectors he can control the spacing between 2 `<p>` elements and even have a different styling for each of them.

Comment: He doesn't want different styling, he wants a background around text that matches the layout of the text, not just a big rectangle.  He also wants there to be a bit of padding at the edge, where line breaks occur.  If you look at the example in his question/comment, you can see where he is going.

Comment: @ChrisMarasti-Georg Oh, understood. So background can be done with my method. For padding at the edge part, I will need to enclose each `<p>` element in another container. That will do it.

Comment: Thanks for trying so hard. The problem is that I want it as semantic as possible, wrapping each paragraph text in an extra div tag doesn't really make a big difference to adding a span inside each paragraph tag.

Comment: @ximi Yea, the extra `<div>` really doesn't help, in this case the `<span>` you use does the work too. Please do post what is the final method you are using :)

Answer (score -1):

Use *display: inline-block;* for your paragraphs

```
body {
    background: url(http://flickholdr.com/800/800) no-repeat;
}

p {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Inline-block does not do what I want. It basically applies the properties of a block element to an inline element, thus causing one solid background in my case, which is exactly not what I want. Thanks for the attempted help nonetheless.

Answer (score -1):

use  with a class name in external style sheet. 
for instance our class name is 
    .myClass
    {
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    }

hence external stye sheet would be needed

Comment: Sorry, but external stylesheet and classes have nothing to do with my problem at all. Thanks for trying though.